# bootstrap-modal don't work in IE

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal

I have a browser issue regarding modal. It just don't work on IE 11 but works pretty fine with firefox and chrome.

```
var chref = $(this).attr('href');
    $('div#tb_modal_confirm_attachment').modal();
    $('#tb_modal_confirm_attachment .modal-footer .btn').click (function () {

             if ($(this).attr('id') == 'confirm_yes') {
                    location.href = chref;
             }
       });



    return false;
```

Comment: Did you copy the line applying the click handler twice? and why not just apply the handler to the "yes" button instead of all the buttons?

Comment: sorry about that. howcome it does not work on IE?

Comment: What do the console logs from the browser say? Are there errors? What version of IE?

Comment: You need to define "don't work" - does the modal not display? does the button not work? Also, what "modal" - jquery UI? custom modal code? I suspect that the issue might be that the handler is getting applied too soon in IE11 and the modal is removing the elements, and their handlers, from the DOM when it re-positions them. But that's just a guess.  You could try using a delegated handler. `$(document).on('click', '#confirm_yes', function() { location.href = chref; });`